# Use arrays to verify numeric inputs

Tags: vb.net

I am an online student learning VB.NET. I have a project I'm working on and was needing some help getting started.

We are learning Arrays and I am struggling a little. I need to create a pin verifier using an array that will check for ranges of numbers for each input.

The application will have 7 text boxes. txtBox1 must be in range 7-9, txtBox2 must be in range 5-7, txtBox3 in range 0-4, txtBox4 in range 0-9, txtBox5 in range 6-9, txtBox 6 in range 3-6, and txtBox7 in range 4-8.

When the Verify button is clicked the array needs to verify each input is within the specified range and then display message if pin is good or not.

I have the code running but I can't verify bad inputs. I need to verify the input is numeric and that it is within the range set.  If input is bad then I need text box to highlight yellow and that box gain focus.  I have tried many variations of IsNumeric and I can't get the text box to gain focus or highlight.

I'm hoping someone can give a clear explanation as to how the code works so that I can continue to do on my own and fully understand what it is I'm doing.  Any help for this future programmer would be appreciated.

```
Option Strict On

Public Class frmPinVerifier
Dim blnOk As Boolean = False

Private Sub btnVerify_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnVerify.Click
    'Arrays
    Dim intMinimum() As Integer = {7, 5, 0, 0, 6, 3, 4}
    Dim intMaximum() As Integer = {9, 7, 4, 9, 9, 6, 8}
    Dim strArrayMessage() As String = {"Must be in range of 7 through 9", "Must be in range of 5 through 7", "Must be in range of 0 through 4", "Must be in range of 0 through 9", "Must be in range of 6 through 9", "Must be in range of 3 through 6", "Must be in range of 4 through 8"}
    Dim intTextBox() As Integer = {CInt(txtBox1.Text), CInt(txtBox2.Text), CInt(txtBox3.Text), CInt(txtBox4.Text), CInt(txtBox5.Text), CInt(txtBox6.Text), CInt(txtBox7.Text)}


    'Start Count
    Dim intCount As Integer = 0


    For intCount = 0 To intMinimum.Length - 1 And intMaximum.Length - 1
        If intTextBox(intCount) >= intMinimum(intCount) And intTextBox(intCount) <= intMaximum(intCount) Then
            blnOk = True
        Else

            MessageBox.Show(strArrayMessage(intCount))

        End If

    Next

    If blnOk = True Then
        MessageBox.Show("PIN Verified")
        txtBox1.Clear()
        txtBox2.Clear()
        txtBox3.Clear()
        txtBox4.Clear()
        txtBox5.Clear()
        txtBox6.Clear()
        txtBox7.Clear()


    End If
```

Comment: I should have noted. I should be able to use a intMinimum and and intMaximum arrays. The intMinimum should hold the minimum value for each digit position and the same for the intMaximum.

Comment: SO works the reverse of that - *you* write some code trying to do what you need to do.  when you get stuck, post a question with code illustrating your problem.  as is you are asking for a tutorial and we dont do that.  you'll learn more by doing it yourself

Comment: I'm not asking for a tutorial I'm asking for some advice on how to get started.  As I said a clear explanation of how the code works not the code.  If you can't help that is fine.

Comment: What is the difference between `a clear explanation` of the code to use and a tutorial?  This is too broad for SO.  It is not for advice, suggestions, ideas, guidance.  Its for answers to issues with code.

Comment: You don't have to help.  I clearly stated I need some help getting started and a clear explanation as to how it works.  I didn't ask for code. If this is outside your spectrum of help that is fine.

Comment: Start by Dim'ing  an array holding the acceptable values, one for each textbox; google create vb.net array and you'll find plenty of examples on how to do that. The last step is just going to be a series of "If MyArray1.Contains(Textbox1.Text) Then"'s ...if you get stuck trying to get that to work, post your code

Comment: I have got my array and my loop.  I feel good about that. The trouble I'm having now is validating inputs. When the application gets a bad input I need it to highlight and focus on that text box.  I have tried using the counter to tell it which text box to go to and I created an array intTextBox to grab it but no luck.

Comment: I have tried intTextBox(intCount).Focus() and intTextBox(intCount).Backcolor = Color.Yellow I have tried putting these directly below MessageBox.Show(strArrayMessage(intCount)).  This has not worked. Hopefully you understand what I am asking.

Comment: Have you learnt about *classes* yet? It would enable a perhaps simpler way of solving the problem.

Comment: @BradWethington The line `For intCount = 0 To intMinimum.Length - 1 And intMaximum.Length - 1` does not do what you think. The `And` operator performs a [bitwise And operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation) on its arguments - in this case it does not matter because the lengths of the arrays are equal.

Comment: @AndrewMorton I see what you are saying but the way it is works.  Does that mean the way I have it wont let it verify the input or is there a way to verify with the way I have the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't seem to have any code to set the focus on or change the backcolor of the textboxes in question.

You can set an array to be references to the textboxes. This makes it easy access the properties of those textboxes. You were close with `Dim intTextBox() As Integer = {CInt(txtBox1.Text),...`, but a bit too specific by using the `.Text` property in the array.

```
Private Sub btnVerify_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnVerify.Click
    Dim nums = {TextBox1, TextBox2, TextBox3, TextBox4, TextBox5, TextBox6, TextBox7}
    Dim intMinimum() As Integer = {7, 5, 0, 0, 6, 3, 4}
    Dim intMaximum() As Integer = {9, 7, 4, 9, 9, 6, 8}
    Dim pinIsValid As Boolean = True

    For Each tb In nums
        tb.BackColor = Color.White
    Next

    For i = 0 To nums.Length - 1
        Dim val = Integer.Parse(nums(i).Text)
        Dim minVal = intMinimum(i)
        Dim maxVal = intMaximum(i)
        If val < minVal OrElse val > maxVal Then
            pinIsValid = False
            nums(i).BackColor = Color.Yellow
            nums(i).Focus()
            'TODO: Adjust "Entry {i + 1}" so it makes sense to the user.
            MessageBox.Show($"Entry {i + 1} must be in the range {minVal} to {maxVal} (inclusive)")
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next

    If pinIsValid Then
        For i = 0 To nums.Length - 1
            nums(i).Text = ""
        Next
        MessageBox.Show("PIN Verified")
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! what about if you enter a non-numeric?  Your code makes sense and I was just missing a few key components. But if you I enter a non-numeric it gets an error on the Integer.Parse(nums(i).Text).  I thought you had to use a counter to find where you are in the index but I guess the parallel array knows where you are at in the code?

Comment: @BradWethington 1) You should investigate using [Int32.TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx). 2) I don't understand what you mean by "parallel arrary" in this context.

Comment: Parallel array means two different arrays running together.  I figured it out. I had to run and IsNumeric Loop prior to the loop verifying if inputs were in within specified range. I didn't realize you could run multiple loops on same button click. Thanks for the help.  I'm slowly getting this but it is very challenging.